# Is such thread-id based synchronization safe and neat?

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, atomic

I have written a small AI program which resolves IQ Twist puzzles. Then as an exercise I parallelized it. Here is the source:
[IQTwist Resolver](https://bitbucket.org/bloGit/iqtwist/src/master/IQTwist_engine/IQTwistResolver.cpp).

The algorithm which searches for the solution is recursive.

I used thread-id based synchronization in the critical part of the recursive function (collecting found shapes to a member array). The crucial parts I'm referring to:

```
bool IQTwistResolver::searchForSolution(const int type, const uint32 a_union)
{
    if (m_stopSearch) //make all other threads unwind recursion and finish
        return false;    

    if (TYPES_COUNT == type) //all types reached and solved - end recursion
    {
        m_mutex.lock();
        if (std::thread::id::id() == m_firstFinder || std::this_thread::get_id() == m_firstFinder)
        {
            m_firstFinder = std::this_thread::get_id();
            m_stopSearch = true;
        }
        m_mutex.unlock();
        return true; //return true to collect the solution and unwind
    }
    ...
```

I'm trying to seek advice from experts:

Does this approach have any possible weaknesses/flaws or overkills (maybe I'm missing some simpler solution)?

Would you use a different method of that 'solution buffer' protection?

Perhaps you'd use a wholly different scheme of parallelization (it's worth to know that too)?

Comment: Well for one, you should **never** manually lock and unlock mutexes in C++. Use `std::lock_guard`, `std::unique_lock`, etc. Aside from that, you should be ok if you're careful. Just remember that a new thread might have the same ID as one that has since terminated

Comment: @Cruz And already I know it was worth to post. I'll amend the lock type, thank you!

Comment: @Cruz Unfortunately declaring any lock wrapper involves more stack processing on behalf of its object. In my case the penalty (3.4 x 10^6 calls per second) results in 8-15% of slowdown upon the whole search (e.g. 0.75s instead of 0.65s). Perhaps this is where naked std::mutex comes in handy (as a whole great idea of the multi-level, flexible, powerful C++?). Still I stick to your hint unless it's high branching factor exponential recursive logic. Or maybe someone has some another idea to mitigate the lock's overhead...

Comment: If you're willing to throw away exception/deadlock safety for speed, then so be it. However, if you're really locking so frequently that it's a performance impact, odds are your parallel algorithm is poorly designed (consider using atomics instead)

Comment: @Cruz The design might be incorrect (feel free to review). The thing is I'm not locking it at all, I'm not even reaching its enclosing 'if' block. You confuse locking with allocating guard's object on the stack every time the function is just called. Anyway, I'll try atomic or I'll return to lock_guard after all (I agree with your priority in safety vs speed issue:) Cheers!

Comment: if you're using `std::lock_guard` (rather than `std::unique_lock`), you should only declare an instance in the block which needs protection, and any decent compiler would be able to avoid stack allocations for it in the case when the block isn't executed, or even just overlay it with lifetime-disjoint objects.

Comment: @Cruz Actually this is different than I reported (to my very surprise): `std::guard_lock` doesn't cause efficiency decrease. With it or without it works as fast. It is the other way - believe me or not - putting std::mutex.lock()/unlock() speeds up a little and I can see it in assembly (though I can't decypher it well). I'll look deeper into it, it's a curious phenomenon for me. The more I can 'calm down' and avoid std::mutex because this speed-up is like 'undeserved' side effect. Thanks again and take care!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution should work as expected, however, using `std::mutex` is the most general and most expensive solution.

Another option is to use [`std::call_once`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) which ensures that only the first thread ever makes the call. I.e. the first thread to find a solution would set the value of the result of the search.

Alternatively, you can use `std::atomic` to avoid using a mutex. And instead of thread id, an address of a thread-specific variable is enough for the purpose of making a distinction between threads.

E.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

class FirstThread {
    static thread_local std::thread::id const thread_id_;
    std::atomic<std::thread::id const*> first_{0};

public:
    std::thread::id const& id() const noexcept {
        return thread_id_;
    }

    bool try_become_first() noexcept {
        std::thread::id const* expected = 0;
        return first_.compare_exchange_strong(expected, &thread_id_, std::memory_order_relaxed, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }

    bool is_first() const noexcept {
        return first_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == &thread_id_;
    }
};

thread_local std::thread::id const FirstThread::thread_id_ = std::this_thread::get_id();

int main() {
    FirstThread ft;

    auto f = [&ft]() {
        ft.try_become_first();
        std::cout << "thread " << ft.id() << " is first: " << ft.is_first() << '\n';
    };
    f();
    std::thread(f).join();
}
```

Outputs:

```
thread 139892443997984 is first: 1
thread 139892384220928 is first: 0
```

Note that if you do not need the real thread id returned by `std::this_thread::get_id()`, you can just use an address of a thread-specific `bool` to identify a distinct thread.

Comment: I'll try it out, thank you!  Btw, why are you using thread_id's pointer as an atomic object and not just directly thread::id (which could be then initialized with id::id() as well)? Is it just a matter of taste or a matter of performance (the need of calling id::id() at compare_ step)??

Comment: @bloody On x86-64, both `std::atomic<T*>` and `std::atomic<std::thread::id>` are lock-free. However, AFAIK, `std::atomic<T*>` is lock-free on all platforms, whereas `std::atomic<std::thread::id>` is not guaranteed to. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_lock_free.

Comment: @bloody Would be interesting the see the impact of this mechanism on your benchmark.

Comment: Actually this is a bit different than I had reported in above comments (to my very surprise) but the conclusion is: neither `std::guard_lock` nor `std::atomic` cause efficiency decrease. With them it works as fast as with no sync measure at all. It is the other way - believe me or not - putting `std::mutex.lock()`/`unlock()` speeds up a little and I can see it in assembly (though I can't decypher it well). Maybe I'll look deeper into it, it's a curious phenomenon for me. And thx again for `std::atomic` realising. It's a concise and flexible tool at once (+1 granted).

Comment: @bloody That could be a code alignment issue. Try compiling with `-O3 -march=native -mtune=native -falign-functions=32 -falign-loops=32` (clang doesn't support `-falign-loops`).

Comment: I'm dealing with VS (not GCC), reportedly it has no equivalents of some of them.

Comment: Be very careful with this: C++ makes no guarantee that the memory location of a given thread local variable won't be reused by another thread if the previous thread has terminated. It's much the same issue with thread ids potentially being reused if the thread with that id has since terminated

Comment: @CruzJean You are quite right, however, I don't see how your non-specific advice applies here and where exactly here one needs to be careful and how. I would like to make the most of your advice, but cannot quite see how. Would you care posting your own answer elaborating on that?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin For instance, suppose a thread is the first to try to become first and succeeds (`is_first()` returns true for it). It then terminates at some point. Another thread starts, and happens to have its thread local in the same address as the "first" thread did (which is no longer in use). The new thread tries to become first (and fails), however `is_first()` will still return true because the address is the same. And thus this is a dangerous method.

Comment: @CruzJean Well, you are describing a different problem, but thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

8 months after I placed that post I realized that for the question:

*"Does this approach have any (...) overkills (maybe I'm missing simpler solution)?"*

the proper answer is: Yes, this is an overkill and code cluttering. All the hassle with thread id and `m_firstFinder` member is unnecessary.

I had already a `bool` variable `m_stopSearch` engaged and this can perfectly serve the same synchronization purpose and so should:

```
bool IQTwistResolver::searchForSolution(const int type, const uint32 a_union)
{
    if (m_stopSearch) //make all other threads unwind recursion and finish
        return false;    

    if (TYPES_COUNT == type) //all types reached and solved - end recursion
    {       
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        if (!m_stopSearch)
        {            
            m_stopSearch = true;
            return true; //return true to collect the solution and unwind
        }
        return false; //make "late" solving thread return false to skip solution collection
    }
    ...
```

I know that anyone may not have actually come across that aspect in such a loose, "not-full-context" question, sorry for the hassle. To keep validity/consistency I supplemented my discovery.